# Time trigger Methods are not Triggered in Azure Web Job

Tags: azure-webjobs

```
static void Main()
{
var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
config.UseTimers();   
var host = new JobHost(config);
host.RunAndBlock();
}

public static void TimerTrig1([TimerTrigger("00:00:02")] TimerInfo timer)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Triggered");
}  

public static void TimerTrig2([TimerTrigger("00:00:04")] TimerInfo timer)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Triggered");
}
```

i have published that code on azure but it give me error
[Click for Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPLcj.png) but i resolve it by setting connection string on Azure portal [Click for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w88Z7.png) . but still noting happened. My Methods are not triggering .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 I have published that code on azure but it give me error Click for Error 
 that "** System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to validate Microsoft 
 Azure WebJobs SDK Dashboard connection string**. " I resolve it by setting 
 connection string on Azure portal [enter image description here][1] [Click 
 for detail][2]. but still noting happened. My Methods were not triggering 
 so after that i Fund out that i have to make my methods public like this 
 [enter image description here][3]. And Finally it run. Output [enter image 
 description here][4]
```